# Why are my model's attributes capitalized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a legacy table that does not follow the default Rails naming convention.

Model class:

```
class TestTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = :test_table
    self.primary_key = :test_table_id

    attr_accessible :param_one, :param_two
```

I can do t = TestTable.new alright but all column attributes are capitalized.

```
t.param_one
```

generates "undefined method".

```
t.PARAM_ONE
```

Does NOT generate any errors.

```
t.inspect
```

shows all column attributes as capitalized.

Comment: Because the DB columns are capitalized?

Comment: Maybe the DB is MSSQL. They like PascalCase there.

Comment: Could be, I'm using sqlite3 this time. I'm used to Oracle where this is not an issue. I'll try regenerating the table using lower case.

Comment: Regenerating with lowercase fixed it. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.